# Captcha on change for span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, onchange

Hi so my goal is to show submit-form once the attribute changes.

```
<span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox recaptcha-checkbox-expired" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label">

<button type="submit" class="Button ctct-button Button--block Button-secondary" id="submit-form" data-enabled="enabled">Sign Up</button>
```

I have tried using JQuery

```
$("#recaptcha-anchor").change(function(){
  alert("Changed!");
  $("#submit-form").show();
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$(".recaptcha-checkbox").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
   alert("This has been clicked");
   $("#submit-form").show();
});
```

Any pointers to what I might be doing wrong? The Alert message does not go off. I have read the JQuery API's for change, but if there is a page that could help me that would be useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event that gets triggered on attribute change.

You should create a custom event for changing attribute and trigger it where you're changing it in code. Then you can listen to it and execute code you want.

Trigger custom event like this in function where attribute gets changed

```
$(".recaptcha-checkbox").trigger('attribute-change');
```

Then make event listener for this event and execute your code.

```
$(".recaptcha-checkbox").on('attribute-change', function(){
   alert("This has been clicked");
   $("#submit-form").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I can't add trigger when it changes, google included their script so I won't be able to trigger it after that. I got around it by showing it after verification.